# Помогите с билдом в юнити!

Tags: unity3d

Проблема заключаетса в том что когда я компилирую игру под виндовс на юнити то игрок становитса слишком быстрый но в игре его скорость нормальная. Если что игра в 2д. А также я пробывал менять настройки в Player settings но я там ничего не смог сделать . Помогите пожалуста!!!

---

вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public int health;
    public int damage_wall;
    public bool go_colonie = false;

    public Wall wall;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool faceRight = false;
    public bool collision_wall;
    private bool in_children_zona;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveX, moveY);

        if (moveX != 0 || moveY != 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRun", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRun", false);
        }

        if (moveX > 0 && faceRight)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if (moveX < 0 && !faceRight)
        {
            flip();
        }

        void flip()
        {
            faceRight = !faceRight;
            transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
        }

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            if (collision_wall == true)
            {
                if (wall.health > 0)
                {
                    wall.Take_Damage(damage_wall);
                }
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (in_children_zona == true)
            {
                go_colonie = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Wall")
        {
            collision_wall = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "ChildrenZona")
        {
            in_children_zona = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: хто хочет посмотреть на код могу выставить

Comment: Никто не хочет, но тут принято помогать другим, а чтобы Вам кто-то помог код надо писать сразу, а не по запросу.

Comment: вангую, что движение в Update и без использования Time.deltaTime

Comment: извините щас скину код и я новичок еще

Answer (score 0):

а всё я решыл проблему. видь в simulated mode было значение FixedUpdate и я в коде тоже Фиксед апдейт поставил и всё заработало

Comment: только не забудьте в FixedUpdate() использовать Time.fixedDeltaTime вместо Time.deltaTime